# why my ajax makes me to refresh my page to see content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want when my ajax detect changes on database automatically show the content in html without refresh , but it isnt doing nothing. I have to refresh the page , how can I fix it? I am trying to do ajax long polling

```
$(function(doc, win, $) {
    var has_focus = true;
    var notification = win.Notification || win.mozNotification || win.webkitNotification;
    var $badge = $("#notifications-badge");
    var $list = $("#notifications-list");
    var $button = $("#notifications-button");
    URL_GET_NOTIFICATION = BASE_URL + 'notify/pusher';
    URL_GET_NOTIFICATION_UPDATE = BASE_URL + 'notify/update';

    if ('undefined' === typeof notification) {
        console.log('Web notification not supported');
    } else {
        notification.requestPermission(function(permission) {});
    }

    function check_notifications(timestamp) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: URL_GET_NOTIFICATION,
            data: { timestamp : timestamp },
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                for (var i in data.notifications) {
                    notify(data.notifications[i].message, data.notifications[i].type, data.notifications[i].timestamp);
                }
                check_notifications(data.timestamp);
            }
        });
    }

    function notify(message, type, created_at) {
        var type_txt = 'info';
        var url = '#';
        var icon = 'info-circle';

        if (type == 0) {
            type_txt = 'success';
            icon = 'check';
        } else if (type == 1) {
            type_txt = 'info';
            icon = 'exclamation';
        } else if (type == 2) {
            type_txt = 'warning';
            icon = 'exclamation-triangle';
        } else if (type == 3 || type == 4) {
            type_txt = 'danger';
            icon = 'fire';
        }

        $badge.show();
        $badge.text(parseInt($badge.text()) + 1);

        $list.find(".item").eq(13).nextAll(".item").remove();
        var item = '<li class="item text-' + type_txt + '"><a href="' + url + '"><span class="text-' + type_txt + '">' +
            '<i class="fa fa-' + icon + ' fa-fw"></i> ' + message.substr(0, 22) + '</span>' +
            '<span class="pull-right text-muted small" data-time="' + created_at + '">X</span></a></li>' +
            '<li class="item divider"></li>';
        $list.prepend(item);

        $('.dropdown.open .dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');

        return true;
    }

    $(win).on("blur", function () {
        has_focus = false;
    });

    $(win).on("focus", function () {
        has_focus = true;
    });

    $button.on("click", function () {
        $badge.fadeOut(300, function () {
            $badge.text(0);
        });

        $list.find("span[data-time]").each(function (index) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.text(moment.unix($this.data('time')).fromNow());
        });
    });

    check_notifications();
}(document, window, jQuery));
```

Comment: You should probably use `setInterval()` to run `check_notifications()` periodically, instead of calling it immediately in the `success` function.

Comment: But it looks like your code should work. Check the Javascript console for errors, and check the Network tab to see if the AJAX request is returning the data you expect.

Comment: when I check on network or javascript erros  dont show nothing , but on network says timestamp=number pending ,but the problem starts when I insert something dont callback again to generate new one

Comment: Try logging error from an error callback.

Comment: Chances are that the Ajax's underlying htmrequest times out.

Comment: no error, no nothing , what should it be?

Comment: Check the log on the server to see if there's a problem running the script.

Comment: this is what the server is returing me {"notifications":[{"user_id":"1","notification_id":"140","timestamp":"1493433290","id":"140","product_id":"4233","message":"1","type":"1","created_at":"1493433290","status":null},{"user_id":"1","notification_id":"141","timestamp":"1493433390","id":"141","product_id":"4232","message":"1","type":"1","created_at":"1493433390","status":null}],"timestamp":1493438979}